# How to write characters in reverse order ( from last to first ) from character variable into integer variable?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: CodeBlocks 20.03 ( MinGW 9.3.0 )

My code is:

```
  function fun_conversion( n_numb_tmp, n_base_tmp ) result( data_tmp )

    integer, intent(in) :: n_numb_tmp
    integer, intent(in) :: n_base_tmp
    integer             ::   data_tmp
    integer             :: n_div, n_div_res
    character(1)        :: char_01
    character(4)        :: char_02
    
    n_div = 0

    n_div = n_numb_tmp / n_base_tmp

    write(char_01,'(i0)') ( n_div * n_base_tmp ) - n_numb_tmp
    
    char_02 = char_01

    do while ( n_div /= 0 )
        
      n_div_res = n_div

      n_div = n_div / n_base_tmp 

      write(char_01,'(i0)') n_div_res - ( n_div * n_baza_tmp )

      char_02 = trim(char_02) // char_01
               
    end do

   ! data_tmp = ?????

  end function fun_conversion
```

How to enter all integer remainders of division from the last remainder to the first in the variable data tmp? The algorithm is in pic attachment

[image: data_tmp]

Comment: I really can't work out what you are asking, maybe an example would help? Are you asking about arrays?

Comment: @IanBush Now i change the code and got a `char_2` and the result is `0621`. How can i write `char_2` to `data_tmp` in reverse order ( from last to first character )?

Comment: what exactly do you take as input? how do you know that `char_02` must always be of length 4?

Comment: @jack The input is any positiv number and the base is number from 1 to 9. I do not know the lenght of `char_02` because i am not expirienced in fortran. Is there way to declare `char_02` for any lenght?

Comment: @HarryKastorp You could be using `character(:), allocatable :: char_02` which can grow.

Comment: @jack Can you show me how to increase lenght afther every step in do loop?

Comment: @HarryKastorp I have updated my answer to include just that.

Comment: @jack Great solution but in my case i need to write only one character in every step in do while loop and in every step to increase the lenght of `char_02` by 1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to reverse a string of constant length you can do it as follows

```
module foo_m
  implicit none
contains
  integer function str2reverted_int(str) result(res)
    character(*), intent(in) :: str

    character(len(str)) :: rev_str
    integer             :: i, n

    n = len(str)

    rev_str(1:1) = str(n:n)
    do i = 2, n
      rev_str(i:i) = str(n+1-i:n+1-i)
    end do

    read (rev_str, *) res
  end function
end module

program main
  use foo_m
  implicit none

  print *, str2reverted_int('1234')     ! -> '4321'
  print *, str2reverted_int('12345')    ! -> '54321'
end program
```